# Using Drupal.settings.basePath in Modernizer / yepnope.js loads

Tags: javascript, drupal-7, modernizr, yepnope

I am currently starting development of drupal sites on Acquia. Using git and working locally is a new workflow for me. When building locally and trying to utilize  Modernizr load / yepnope, my JS in my script.js file typically looks like this..

```
Modernizr.load([
    {
    test: Modernizr.mq('only all'),
    nope: '/sitename/docroot/sites/all/themes/theme/js/libs/polyfill.js'
    },
    ....
```

So that works locally on my machine, but when I commit my changes and push to my acquia development server the file path for the loaded scripts is incorrect, since it's not the same setup I guess.

http://mysite.devcloud.acquia-sites.com/mysite/docroot/sites/all/themes/theme/js/libs/polyfill.js

It needs to be the below, without the mysite/docroot in the URL.

http://mysite.devcloud.acquia-sites.com/sites/all/themes/theme/js/libs/polyfill.js

So that brings me to Drupal.settings.basePath. If I print this out it gives me /mysite/docroot/ on my local setup. If I do it on the dev server, it would print out something different (probably just / ).

So me being the amateur assumed I could do something like this.. (forgive the poor sample, I know it can be done better)

```
var myroot = Drupal.settings.basePath

Modernizr.load([
{
test: Modernizr.mq('only all'),
nope: myroot + 'sites/all/themes/theme/js/libs/polyfill.js'
},
....
```

And this of course does not work. Just returns query1 is not defined.

So I am sure there are faults in many of my attempts to make this work.. so if anyone can suggest something to me, either workflow related or how to fix my setup / code, that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Can you log out Drupal.settings.basePath and let us know what it contains?

Comment: On my local machine it shows "/sitename/docroot/", which is correct. On the dev server after being pushed, it shows "/", as expected. I just need to get this path into the nope: 'path/to/polyfill.js'

Comment: Hi, you'll need to show more code (or live example) in order to get help. The code you just show up seems correct, so the problem probably come from elsewhere. Is the global `Drupal` is declared before your script tag?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I just have a different local setup when using Acquia, but why not just use a relative path like  /sites/all/themes/theme/js/libs/polyfill.js?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit late but it may help anyway :

Try something like :

```
var jsFolderPath = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host+ Drupal.settings.basePath + 'sites/all/themes/theme/js/libs/';

nope: jsFolderPath + 'polyfill.js'
```

Then you easily add polyfills for each yesnope, regardless of being in dev server or in locahost.